# What happens if a creditor can't make it to the creditors meeting for bankruptcy?

Tags: bankruptcy

I am in the US, and have some foreign debts I will be declaring in my bankruptcy application, as well as some US debts where the people have since moved overseas.

It's unlikely anyone living overseas or representing a foreign org would show up to the creditors meetings.

I know that it is already unlikely that people show up, but my question is if they are unable to due to being overseas, does that give grounds for the bankruptcy to be challenged at a later stage?

Comment: Are you sure those debts are dischargeable under (United States?) bankruptcy law?

Comment: @RonBeyer yes. I've talked to lawyers. It doesn't discharge those debts that are in foreign countries, but it ensures those debts can't be collected in the US. Besides the question also refers to US debts but where the individual has moved overseas.

Comment: I was referring directly to the foreign debts that your question references. Please add tags for your jurisdiction, different countries have different laws.

Comment: @RonBeyer done, thee question should be clearer now.

Comment: @DolphSmudgeon Is there a reason you can't ask those lawyers this question?

Comment: @Studoku yes there is, and besides, I think this question and others I ask may be useful to people in the future. I'm not asking for any legal advice, I'm asking everything as a matter of law. If nothing else I'm interested in an answer that gives the why's and hows due to my own curiosity, and lawyers may not wish to waste their time explaining the details to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Most creditors don’t turn up at creditors meetings

Largely because it’s a waste of their time and incurs further expense on top of the money they will likely never see again. Unsecured creditors have virtually no power to control the bankruptcy.

Almost all those who do, do so by proxy - usually nominating the trustee as their proxy. Proxy forms are distributed with the paperwork about the meeting, sign it, stamp it and drop it in the mail and you are “at” the meeting.

Attendance is voluntary - not being there in person or by proxy will not invalidate anything done at the meeting.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might be the case that creditors had to be served and if they were unable to be that could complicate things for the person filing.